# Get multiple state from redux in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

Im going to create an app to shows top 5 cryptocurrencies price.
I create a list of coins and pass it to FlatList and every card is specific coin details. But in my implementation all cards shows same price and that is expected because I have just single price in state. Appreciate for any idea help in this matter.

coinReducer.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  price: '',
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COIN_PRICE:
      return { ...state, price: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

coinAction.js

```
const URL = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP,BCH,EOS&tsyms=USD';

export const getCoinPrice = (symbol) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(URL);
    return dispatch({
      type: COIN_PRICE,
      payload: response.data.RAW[symbol].USD.PRICE,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
 }
};
```

cardSection.js

```
class Card extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getCoinPrice(this.props.item.symbol);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          this.props.price
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  price: state.coinPrice.price
}), { getCoinPrice })(Card);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can keep all the currency's price in the store instead of fetching and update only one of them every time.

Change your reducer into:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  price: {},
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COIN_PRICE:
      return { ...state, price: { ...state.price, action.payload } };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And then change the action into

```
const URL = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP,BCH,EOS&tsyms=USD';
export const getCoinPrice = (symbol) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(URL);
    const payload = {};
    payload[symbol] = response.data.RAW[symbol].USD.PRICE;
    return dispatch({
      type: COIN_PRICE,
      payload,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
 }
};
```

And finally your component into:

```
class Card extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getCoinPrice(this.props.item.symbol);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {this.props.price[this.props.item.symbol]}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  price: state.coinPrice.price
}), { getCoinPrice })(Card);
```

Comment: This would re-render all cards after each fetch.  For efficiency perhaps reducer can just update price[action.payload.symbol] and mapStateToProps should just map state.coinPrice.price[ownProps.symbol]